# Corrective random generation to fit a preset distribution when combined with biased data

Tags: distributions, random-generation

I have a source of data that will have an unknown distribution. I want to generate "random" data such that, when I combine the two, the overall distribution completely hides what the original data's distribution is.

It doesn't matter what I get at the end, so long as it is completely unrelated to the original.

I can't simply drown the signal in noise because:

1. I can only add a finite amount of random data.
2. This needs to be repeatable a large number of times with the same starting distribution, without someone being able to infer it.

The only idea I have so far is to use a probability density function that accounts for the original/target distributions to eliminate the original bias, but I'd prefer to use known methods, if they exist.